# Buttons, Seques, and If/Else Statements

Tags: ios, xcode, button, segue

I have a button that when pressed will determine if the inputted text is equal to a string. If it is, then it will transition to the next view. If it is incorrect, it will change the label text to an error message. It's not working. Can someone critique and let me know what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code:
    - (IBAction)submitButton:(UIButton *)sender {

```
if ([_pinTextField.text isEqualToString:@"1234"]) {
    _errorLabel.text = @"PIN Accepted";
    sleep(1);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:self];
}

else _errorLabel.text = @"Incorrect PIN";
```

}

The segue is happening wether the if else statement is true. How do I fix that?

Comment: What does "It's not working" mean?

Comment: The segue is happening wether the if else statement is true or not. How do I fix that?

Comment: This looks ok (Other than using sleep() on the main thread which is not good) so maybe you wired up something wrong..

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884619/conditional-segue-from-uitableview-to-detailview-based-on-object-state

Comment: I removed the sleep. Not sure why I put that there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the debugger is showing that it doesn't execute the...

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:self];
```

...line, then it's probably a problem with the beginning of the segue as defined in the storyboard.  (It should begin with the view controller instead of the button if you want to trigger it in code.)

(If that line **does** get executed then there's something wrong with the `isEqualToString:` test...but that doesn't look likely.)

Comment: How do I view the debugger? Dumb question but it doesn't show anything in the "All Output" area.

Comment: Also, the segue was triggered by the "Submit" button. How do I code it to begin with the View Controller?

Comment: Nevermind I have figured it out. I had to create a segue from controller to controller to make it function! Thanks everyone for your help.